# 'Auto' option missing for TreeView subclass

Tags: wpf, treeview

I've created a custom control that subclasses TreeView. Right now it's completely empty, doesn't override anything. However when I place an instance in the designer the 'Auto' value for the Width and Height fields is no longer available as it is with the default TreeView. What am I missing?

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean when you say "the 'Auto' value for the Width and Height fields is no longer available"?  In other words, what does the designer do differently?  Also, which designer are you using?  For example, are you using the designer in Expression Blend, in VS 2008, or some other designer?

Answer (score 0):

The width and height fields were specified to 300 in the custom control's XAML when it was created, I didn't notice :(